# How can you use "use framework "foundation" and "use scripting additions" with "open for access"?

Tags: applescript

Every time when I try "open for access" I have a file error found (current application kann nicht in Typ «class fsrf» umgewandelt werden./current application can not be transfer red in type "class fsrf").
Below an example script that does not work with "use framework foundation", but it works without "use framework foundation"

```
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

set path1 to ((path to documents folder) as text) & "GBF:Tbl1:tblGBF.txt"
set tabelle to {}
set file1 to open for access file (path1)
set cc to get eof file1
if cc > 0 then
    set tabelle to read file1 as list
end if
close access file1

display dialog (count of tabelle)
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found a solution:

```
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"

set path1 to ((path to documents folder) as text) & "GBF:Tbl1:tblGBF.txt"
```

(*neu*)    tell application "System Events" to set {name:"tblGBF"} to file path1

```
set tabelle to {}
```

(*neu*)    set file1 to open for access (path1)
set cc to get eof file1
if cc > 0 then
set tabelle to read file1 as list
end if
close access file1

```
display dialog (count of tabelle)
```

Answer (score 0):

The **use** cases are only relevant if you write AppleScriptObjC code which you don't. Delete the lines

```
use scripting additions
use framework "Foundation"
```

`System Events` is not needed. Basically your first line is correct. As `open for access` accepts also POSIX paths (without the `file` keyword) I would prefer that.

And it's highly recommended to handle a possible read/write error

```
set filePath to POSIX path of (path to documents folder) & "GBF/Tbl1/tblGBF.txt"
set tabelle to {}
try
    set fileDescriptor to open for access filePath
    set cc to get eof fileDescriptor
    if cc > 0 then
        set tabelle to read fileDescriptor as list
    end if
    close access fileDescriptor
on error
    try
        close access filePath
    end try
end try

display dialog (count of tabelle)
```

Answer (score 0):

And what about the System Event? The problem with the **file specifier** in **AsObjC** is a problem known to many users for a long time. This is a known bug. Instead, you just need to use other file references. For example, in the source code of the question, it is enough to apply the **coercion as alias** and open for access this alias:

```
use framework "Foundation"
use scripting additions

set Path1 to ((path to documents folder as text) & "GBF:Tbl1:tblGBF.txt") as alias

set tabelle to {}
set file1 to open for access Path1
set cc to get eof file1
if cc > 0 then set tabelle to read file1 as list
close access file1

display dialog (count of tabelle)
```

**NOTE**: I leave the **use framework "Foundation"** as is because it is assumed the user has some AsObjC commands in the rest of script.